# Practical Value of Sufficient Statistics

Tags: machine-learning, sufficient-statistics

Can anyone provide some comments about the practical value of sufficient statistics research? Nearly all sufficiency results, such as the Fisher-Neyman factorization rule, build upon parametric models that assume a known type of distribution but unknown parameters.

However, most real data are not easily modeled using distributions, and non-parametric approaches and machine learning techniques are gaining popularity. What is the practical value of the parametric-model-based sufficient statistics research in modern statistics?

Comment: Outside exponential families, there is no sufficient statistics (besides the order statistic).

Comment: @Xi'an, do you mean the practical value of sufficient statistics is quite limited?

Comment: If you start with the assumption that the data are normal, then the sample mean and sample variance are sufficient statistics. For example, you will not get better estimates of the population mean $\mu$ by using the sample median or the midrange instead of the sample mean. However, when we can't assume that data are from a normal pop., we may need to look at other measures of centrality and dispersion for the best analysis of the data. // Nonparametric statistical methods, incl. permutation tests and bootstrap CIs may rely on using the entire sample instead of simpler sufficient statistics.

Comment: For an interesting post with references you could like see https://danmackinlay.name/notebook/nearly_sufficient_statistics.html, and this [stored google search](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=sufficientstatistics+and+machine+learning%3F)